# Can I custom condition min/max a number field in Contact Form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

First, I have more than 100 products and different price. I want my contact form validation a price. So I declare a variable like this in PHP file.

```
$discount = 70/100;
$disc_price = $price * $discount;
```

It's possible to get a variable `$price` replace in `min:$price`

[number number-111 min: max:]

or have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try Dom events https://contactform7.com/dom-events/
or

```
function action_wpcf7_before_send_mail( $contact_form ) { 
 // var_dump($contact_form);
};

add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'action_wpcf7_before_send_mail', 10, 1 );
```